# How to store working hours in a NoSQL database/ElasticSearch for fastest querying?

Tags: json, algorithm, elasticsearch, nosql

I have working hours in this format

```
Monday 12:00pm to 5pm
       11:00pm to 3am
```

Basically, i tried to convert all to 24hrs Format

So therefore

```
Monday 1200 to 1700
       2300 to 300
```

So Now, i can query this from NoSQL in this way,

```
if input_hours > start_hours AND input_hours < end_hours
```

However, this will not work for businesses like nightclubs which are open

for instance `11:00pm to 3:00am -> 2300 to 300` (The above condition fails `2am = 200` is not greater than `2300`) and i'd have to write slightly complex queries

I'm using Elastic search

Can there be a more query-optimized implementation of working hours in the database?

I'm trying to find the businesses that are open at any given time

Comment: If a business is open after midnight, you could keep increasing the hour, i.e. 24:00pm => 2400, 3am => 2700, etc.

Comment: I've seen a similar requirement before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823419/find-open-shops-through-timetable-with-elasticsearch-tire

Comment: @AndreiStefan That looks good, How about using some inbuilt formats into elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html does that workout well?